# How to get plain text with Xpath

Tags: html, xpath

Hi I got this piece of html and i want to get text elements from it

```
<span id="product_description" itemprop="description" class="">
    <h1>Toltec Lighting 216-BRZ-508 Leaf Collection Traditional Potrack With Italian Marble Glass In Bronze</h1>
    <br class="">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;" class="">MANUFACTURE: </span>
    Toltec Lighting
    <br class=" xh-highlight">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;" class="">COLLECTION: </span>
    Leaf
    <br class=" xh-highlight">
</span>
```

I want to get list of values. In this case it will be "Toltec Lighting" and "Leaf"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this :

```
//span[@id='product_description']/text()
```

or if you need to also make sure no empty text nodes selected :

```
//span[@id='product_description']/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Comment: I would like to include the text value also. how could i achieve that? Is below one worked?     //span[@id='product_description']/text()['COLLECTION: ']

Answer (score -1):

You may try using this:

```
//*[text()='Toltec Lighting']
```